# $\omega_1$-like elementary chains from long countable elementary chains

Tags: model-theory, ordinal-numbers

For some countable first-order theory $T$, if we have a linearly ordered set $I$ and an elementary chain $\{\mathfrak{A}_i\}_{i\in I}$ we can form a structure $\mathfrak{A}_{I}^\star = (\bigcup_{i\in I}\mathfrak{A}_i,\leq)$ where $\leq$ is a new binary predicate interpreted by $x\leq y \leftrightarrow (\forall i\in I)(y\in \mathfrak{A}_i \rightarrow x\in\mathfrak{A}_i)$. The theory of this structure implies that every $\leq$ initial segment is an elementary sub-structure of the whole structure relative to the original language.

A small modification of Hodges' proof of Vaught's two-cardinal theorem, from 'Building Models by Games,' gives us this statement:

> For a countable first-order theory $T$, if $\kappa$ is an uncountable regular cardinal, and $\{\mathfrak{A}_i\}_{i\in\kappa}$ is a proper elementary chain of models of $T$ (Edit: We also need that for each $i\in\kappa$, $|A_i|<\kappa$), then there exists a structure $\mathfrak{B}$ such that $\mathfrak{A}_\kappa^\star \equiv \mathfrak{B}$ and $\mathfrak{B}$ is $\omega_1$-like (i.e. $|B|=\omega_1$, but for every $x\in B$, $|\{y\in B|\mathfrak{B}\models y\leq x\}|=\omega$).

My question is whether or not you can push this in the other direction: For every first-order theory $T$, does there exist a countable ordinal $\alpha_T$ such that if $\{\mathfrak{A_i} \}_{i\in\alpha_T}$ is a proper elementary chain of models of $T$, then there exists a structure $\mathfrak{B}$ such that $\mathfrak{A}_{\alpha_T}^\star \equiv \mathfrak{B}$ and $\mathfrak{B}$ is $\omega_1$-like?

Edit: The condition about the size of the models that I forgot makes a countable analog seem more difficult, but it still feels like there ought to be some weak analog involving countable admissible ordinals or something.

Comment: Does $\kappa$ in your statement need to be uncountable? Otherwise taking $\alpha_T = \omega$ works for every $T$.

Comment: Yes it does need to be uncountable.

Comment: Probably I am missing something: starting from an infinite model of $T$, why can't one always build a proper elementary chain of arbitrary ordinal length using simply the Compactness Theorem?  And in your definition of $\leq$ for $\mathfrak A^\star_I$, are $x$ and $y$ really meant to appear in this order?

Comment: The order of $x$ and $y$ was backwards, thank you. Yes you can always build arbitrarily long elementary chains but you can't necessarily build one with certain properties. The motivating example is the kind of elementary chain you build in the proof of the two-cardinal theorem. In such a chain there is a definable set that is constant along the chain.

Comment: What is the non-script $B$ appearing in the last line of your highlighted text?

Comment: That is the underlying set of the structure $\mathfrak{B}$.

Comment: @JamesHanson What do you require the elementary chain to preserve in your question?

Comment: @LawrenceWong The way the question is written I want the elementary chains to be elementarily equivalent in the expanded language that can talk about the chains. This is hodges proof gets us starting from an uncountable chain of regular length.